# why is my function called twice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a swipe recognizer attached to cells in my table view

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

      //swipe recognition
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *g = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellWasSwiped:)];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:g];
        [g release];


    }


    // Configure the cell...
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" number %d", indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

and the swipe function is

```
- (void)cellWasSwiped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)g {
    NSLog(@"sunt in cellWasSwiped");
    swipeViewController *svc = [[swipeViewController alloc]init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
  [svc release];
}
```

and by introducing breakpoints i see that my swipe function is called 2 times and there are two identical view controllers pushed on my navigation controller. Why is my swipe function called twice when i swipe a cell?

Comment: did u make sure that the swipe is being done only once?

Comment: also try adding the gesture to the contentView of cell rather than cell.

Comment: The way you're doing it it's adding a gesture recognizer for each individual cell. Try adding only one to the whole tableView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `cellWasSwiped` can be called multiple times on change of `UIGestureRecognizer` state. You need to check property `state`, it will be `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` when user finished his action. It's also good to check for states `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed` and `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled`.

Answer (score 3):

I had that same specific problem with swiping in a table cell. My recognizer method was called twice with state UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded.

I worked around it as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    //... create cell
    //... create swipe recognizer (in my case attached to cell's contentView)
  }

  for (UIGestureRecognizer* g in cell.contentView.gestureRecognizers)
    g.enabled = YES;
}
```

and then

```
-(void) cellWasSwiped: (UIGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {

  if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    return;

  if (recognizer.enabled == NO)
    return;

  recognizer.enabled = NO;

  //... handle the swipe
  //... update whatever model classes used for keeping track of the cells
  // Let the table refresh
  [theTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: For some reason in iOS 5 I wasn't needing to check the enabled state. My thought is that iOS 5 respects the enable/disable state and 4.3 does not. Once I added a check for the enabled state everything was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the gesture recognizer to the cell directly, you can add it to the tableview in `viewDidLoad`.

In the `cellWasSwiped`-Method you can determine the affected IndexPath and cell as follows:

```
-(void)cellWasSwiped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

  if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint swipeLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
        UITableViewCell* swipedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
        // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: i get a SIGABRT at line "CGPoint swipeLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView: self.tableView];"

Comment: verify ur tableview is synthesized if not then use ur tableviewname

Comment: my tableview is not synthesized .. and i don't know at what you refer when you talk about tableviewname .. i'm new to obj-c, sorry

Comment: CGPoint swipeLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:tableViewobjectName];

Comment: like this to all where u have use self.tableview.change this to tableview by remove self with dot